# output.packageApplication.outputDirectory.toPath() - not build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

Android Studio 3.5

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-beta01'
```

in app/build.gradle:

```
            def releaseOutputFileName = "${rootProject.name}_${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk"
            def packageAppOutputDirPath = output.packageApplication.outputDirectory.toPath()
```

But I get error:

```
com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.ExternalApiUsageException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar.toPath() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```